# How to append a string from one row to another, based on another duplicate value

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, data-cleaning

I have a dataset with several duplicate 'Email' fields, which I'd like to use as a uniqueID. However, each duplicate contains unique information about user 'Tags' that I'd like to compile and keep before deleting.

EXAMPLE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[1234, 'Customer A', '123 Street', np.nan, np.nan],
               [1234, 'Customer A', np.nan, '333 Street', np.nan],
               [1234, 'Customer A', '12345 Street', np.nan, np.nan],
               [1234, 'Customer A', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
               [1233, 'Customer B', '444 Street', '3335 Street', np.nan],
               [1233, 'Customer B', '555 Street', '666 Street', np.nan],
               [1233, 'Customer B', '553 Street', '666 Street', 'abc@email.com'],
               [1235, 'Customer C', '1553 Street', '644 Street', 'abc@email.com'],
               [1235, 'Customer C', '2553 Street', '644 Street', 'abc@email.com']],     
               columns=['ID', 'Customer', 'Billing Address', 'Shipping Address', 'Contact'])
df.head()
```

```
    ID      Customer    Billing Address Shipping Address     Contact
0   1234    Customer A  123 Street      NaN                  NaN
1   1234    Customer A  NaN             333 Street           NaN
2   1234    Customer A  12345 Street    NaN                  NaN
3   1234    Customer A  NaN             NaN                  NaN
4   1233    Customer B  444 Street      3335 Street          NaN
```

I'd like to consolidate the `Contact` information for each row labeled 'Customer A' into the final row, separated by a `,` The end result would be `NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN` (or whatever other string data is in each field, just consolidated and separated by a column).

Here's what I've tried, but there has to be a more elegant solution.
After sorting by `Email` field:

```
def row_clean(df):
    for i in range(0, len(df)-1):
        if df.loc[i,'Customer'] == np.NaN:
            return df
        elif df.loc[i,'Customer'] == df.loc[(i+1),'Customer']:
            df.loc[(i+1),'Contact'] = str(df.loc[(i+1),'Contact']) + ', ' + str(df.loc[i,'Contact'])            
    return df

row_clean(df)
```

Any thoughts here? Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the output `NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN` is not possible. You can have the string `'NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN'` (each value is no longer recognized as null) or the list `[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]` but not 4 `np.NaN` just floating around.

Comment: Thanks ALoilz, the output I gave is just an example, in my real dataset, I'm trying to combine tag numbers, so the output would read `tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4`. I'd rather not lose the tag data when I drop duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```
customers=df["Customer"].unique().tolist()
List=[]

for customer in customers: 
    List.append(df.loc[df["Customer"]==customer,"Contact"].tolist())

df=df.drop_duplicates("Customer",keep="first")
df["new"]=List
```

output

```
Out[10]: 
     ID    Customer  ...        Contact                             new
0  1234  Customer A  ...            NaN            [nan, nan, nan, nan]
4  1233  Customer B  ...            NaN       [nan, nan, abc@email.com]
7  1235  Customer C  ...  abc@email.com  [abc@email.com, abc@email.com]

[3 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: I think that's it! Thank you, a much better solution!